# Devolver array de objetos por AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, array

estoy desarrollando un sistema de ventas, y en la ventana de ticket tengo el boton buscar que permite ir a otra pagina con el listado de articulos. Este consta dfe dos botones. Uno es agregar que añade el producto en cuestion a un array de detalles del objeto ticket(trabajo con MVC y POO), y elotro un terminado que retorna a la ventana anterior

Clase ticket  y detalle.

```html
<?php
require_once ("includes/claseConexion.php");
require_once ("claseProducto.php");

class detalleTicket{
    
    private $idp;
    private $precio;
    private $cantidad;
    private $nombre;
    private $subtotal;
    
   
   public function __construct($id,$pu,$cant,$nom){
    
    
    $this->idp=$id;
    $this->precio=$pu;
    $this->cantidad=$cant;
    $this->nombre=$nom;
    $this->subtotal= ($this->cantidad * $this->precio);
   
   }
   public function setSubtoal($sub){
    
    $this->subtotal=$sub;
    
   }
   public function actualizaCantidad($nueva){
    
    $this->cantidad=$this->cantidad + $nueva;
    $sub= $this->cantidad * $this->precio;
     $this->setSubtoal($sub);    
    
   }
}
class Ticket{
  private $id;
  private $detalle = array();
  private $fecha;
  private $hora;
  private $total;
  private $stm;
  private $vuelto; 
  
  public function __construct($f,$h){
    
    $this->fecha=$f;
    $this->hora=$h;
    
  }
  public function agregaDetalle($d){
    
    $this->detalle[] = $d;
  } 
  public function setTotal($val){
    
    $this->total=$val;
    
  }
public function listarArt(){
    
  return $this->detalle();
}
public function registrar(){
    //me conecto a la bd
    $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion(); 
 try{

    $conexion->beginTransaction();
    $queryid="select comprobante from identificadores;"; 
     $array=$conexion->query($queryid);
   foreach($array as $a){
    $id = $a['comprobante'];
      }
 
  $qnuevoid="UPDATE identificadores SET comprobante=".++$id.";";
  $conexion->query($qnuevoid);
  
        $queryticket="insert into despensa.ticket (idticket, fecha, total,vuelto) values (".$id.",'".$this->fecha."',56,88);";
  $conexion->query($queryticket);

   $conexion->commit();
   
 }catch(Exception $e){
   $conexion->rollBack();
     echo "Fallo: " . $e->getMessage(); 
 }
 

    
}
}


?>
```

El problema que tengo es que quiero listar los articulos añadidos al carrito al retornar a la pagina y me da un error de parseo de JSON: REQUESTED JSON PARSE FAILED.

Para lo mismo tengo un codigo jquery intermedio y un archivo de poroceso:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
listarDetalle();

});
function listarDetalle(){
     var accion="listar";
    $.ajax({
       
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: { "accion":accion}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            
            success: function(data){
           content=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+data[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");                 
       
    
               
            }
        
  

        } 
        
}).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});;

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Osea en el ready del documento listo los articulos pero me da error:

```html
<?php

include ("claseTicket.php");
$ticket = new Ticket($fecha,$hora);

function listarProductos(){
    $arrayarticulos=$ticket->listarArt();
     echo json_encode($arrayarticulos);
    
}
if (isset($_POST['accion'])){
   if ($_POST['accion']="listar"){
       $arrayarticulos=$ticket->listarArt();
     echo json_encode($arrayarticulos);
    
   }else if ($_POST['accion']="agregar"){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $precio = $_POST['precio'];
    $cant=$_POST['cantidad'];
    $nom=$_POST['nombre'];
    $registro = new detalleTicket($id,$precio,$cant,$nom);
    $ticket->agregaDetalle($registro);
   } 
}

?>
```

La verdad no se que puede ser..el error es:
Error en la peticion ajax..Requested JSON parse failed.

Comment: que error te da? , creo que eso lo deberías mostrar igual,

Comment: Error en la peticion ajax..Requested JSON parse failed.

Comment: Caruso , eso especificarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Verificaste que la petición trae datos y cómo los trae mediante un console.log  que puedes poner aquí:  `success: function(data){
 console.log(data);` Ya como comentario adicional, deberías considerar mejorar la parte del  `fail` con todos esos `if`. Mejor crea un array con los códigos y los mensajes que quieres por cada uno y así imprimes el mensaje en base al código de error.

Answer (score 2):

Te falta indicarle al navegador que los encabezados de retorno tienen un formato con esta instrucción `header('Content-Type: application/json');`
Recuerda que para que no haya errores el array en PHP se recomienda sea un arreglo asociativo
Por ejemplo

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arr = array('foo'=>'Valor foo', 'bar' => 'Valor bar');
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

Así quedaría tu código del controlador

```
<?php  
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    include ("claseTicket.php");
    $ticket = new Ticket($fecha,$hora);

    function listarProductos(){
        $arrayarticulos=$ticket->listarArt();
         echo json_encode($arrayarticulos);

    }
    if (isset($_POST['accion'])){
       if ($_POST['accion']="listar"){
           $arrayarticulos=$ticket->listarArt();
         echo json_encode($arrayarticulos);

       }else if ($_POST['accion']="agregar"){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $precio = $_POST['precio'];
        $cant=$_POST['cantidad'];
        $nom=$_POST['nombre'];
        $registro = new detalleTicket($id,$precio,$cant,$nom);
        $ticket->agregaDetalle($registro);
       } 
    }

    ?>
```

Que te sirva

Comment: El array es un atributo de la clase ticket, es un objeto de detalleticket, asi que es asociativo, tiene atributo->valor. Estoy probando y me llega un array vacio. Puse console.log en el codigo ajax del boton agregar y anda perfecto.

Comment: el getter del array esta bien o va sin parentesis: return $this->detalle();

Answer (score 1):

Prueba haciendo un parse a data en el método success:

```
content = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: me devuelve un array vacio. Pero el metodo agregar no falla, me muestar un agregado en console.log que yo mismo puse

Comment: Prueba colocando `echo json_encode($arrayarticulos,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`

Comment: Probe y sigue devolviendo Array[] vacio en la consola, probablemente sea de php el error, no estoy añadiendo los detalles, pienso.

Comment: El ultimo bloque de código que pusiste, ¿por qué crea un nuevo ticket?, si este es el archivo que invoca el ajax, entonces en cada invocación se crea un ticket vacío, puede que ahí se derive todo el problema.

Comment: Te entiendo.. y donde invoco el constructor de la clase ticket? o deberia usar una sesion de manera que se cree una vez nomas?

Comment: Puedes manejarla en una sesión para solo crearla una vez y modificar los productos en cada petición. No olvides vaciar tu ticket al finalizar la compra para evitar productos de más.

Comment: Esta bien..en el index de ticket deberia crear un objeto e inciar la sesion? Y luego ticket.js llama al proceso, y este comprueba si ya esta creado?

Comment: Incia session, inicializas ticket, revisa la documentación http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php. En cuanto en donde hacer la inicialización depende, si usas un framework revisa su documentación para ver donde es mejor, si no pues en tu archivo de arranque o en la primer página.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba formateando el json.

```
 function listarDetalle(){
     var accion="listar";
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: JSON.stringify({accion}), 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
           content=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+data[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buscando encontre alguno errores que me autocorrijo, el metodo agregardetalle la variable $d es de tipo detalleticket:

```html
 public function agregaDetalle(detalleTicket $d){
    
    $this->detalle[] = $d;
  }
```

En listarArt, no lleva parentesis porque no es una funcion es una variable:

```html
public function listarArt(){
    
  return $this->detalle;
}
```

Luego el array de articulos se declara con corchetes:

```html
$arrayarticulos[]=$ticket->listarArt();
```

Y otra cuestion es si quiero agregar varios detalles de ticket que tenmgo que cambiar para que no se pise el valor